# Is there any difference between using Dataframe.columns and Dataframe.keys() to obtain the column names?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For the sake of curiosity is there any practical difference between getting the column names of a DataFrame (let's say df) by using df.columns or df.keys()?

I've checked the outs by type and it seems to be exactly the same. Am I missing something or these two methods are just as redundant as it seems? Is one more appropriate to use than the other?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-keys/

Comment: Yes, but doest it make any difference using .keys() or .columns? Or am I overthinking it? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: I have never used `pandas` but it seems (from the info in the link) that there are at least 3 types of dataframes and for the plain one columns and keys are going to be identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't look like there's a practical difference and if there is, I'd really like to know what it is. You probably saw in the documentation that [DataFrame.columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) has the column labels and it is an axis property and [DataFrame.keys](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.keys.html) gets the info axis. I would think that since the former is an attribute or reference and the latter a callable method, the method takes a little more time to execute. I have not tested this but I'm pretty sure that, even if there's a difference, it is not significant. Also they both return the same type:

```
>>> type(data.columns)
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>
>>> type(data.keys())
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>
```

Answer (score 5):

one difference I noticed That you can Use .keys() with Series but You can not use .columns with Series .